# Why doesn't myString.at(myString.length()) work?

Tags: c++, string

I'm including the `<string>` library at the top of my .cpp file but when I test it out

```
 cout<<myString.at(myString.length());
```

It should print out the last letter of the string, or at least I think it should. But my compiler throws a hissy fit and spits back a bunch of jargon at me.

I'm used to writing in JavaScript so I'm not used to, well....having rules, so to me this makes perfect sense to return the last character of the string.

Comment: Perhaps you could put effort into reading the "hissy fit", or at the very least show it to us? In any case, the length of an array is never a valid index into it.

Comment: The JavaScript equivalent of that code wouldn't return the last character of a string, either. You clearly haven't given your task enough thought. You don't know JavaScript as well as you think you do, so it's unwise to try to ascribe too much similarity between it and C++.

Comment: @RobKennedy Very true, but it's also unwise to ascribe too much similarity between JavaScript and C++ even if you know JS *very* well. The just don't share much beyond a syntactic similarity.

Answer (score 7):

String indexes are zero-based so run [0..myString.length()-1].  You should use

```
myString.at(myString.length()-1);
```

to get the last character

Comment: this worked. I just had a flashback to a tutoring session where the professor told me that each string array has that "/0" null value thing at the end. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Glad it helped.  Note that C strings (a `char` array) have a `'\0'` at the end but C++ `std::string` does not.

Answer (score 2):

it should be

`cout <<myString.at(myString.length()-1 );`

as string indexes are 0 based, hence a string "hello" will have indexes from 0 to 4, and a length of 5.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
  string myString = "hello";
  cout << myString.at(myString.length()-1 ); //outputs "o"

}
```

demo : http://codepad.org/QxwrjpIt

Answer (score 1):

Did you include namespace `std` ?

Also it should be 1 less than the length to account for zero-based indexing

`std::cout<<myString.at(myString.length()-1);`

Answer (score 0):

Because string is indexed as array... position at length() is out of bounds.

You should use `length() - 1`

Full example: `cout << myString.at(myString.length() - 1);`

Answer (score 0):

Since we start counting at zero, you need the `length - 1` to get the last character.

```
std::cout << myString.at(myString.length()-1) << std::endl;
```